RISC-V GNU Compiler Toolchain
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake autotools-dev curl python3 python3-pip libmpc-dev libmpfr-dev libgmp-dev gawk build-essential bison flex texinfo gperf libtool patchutils bc zlib1g-dev libexpat-dev ninja-build git cmake libglib2.0-dev libslirp-dev
$: command not found

installed all the required packages, still facing the same issue.

Why are you installing things the OS already has?

@David Ubuntu does not have all these packages on the default installation. Perhaps OP is using some tutorial which instructs to install all these packages

Python? It should have at least that so my question is still valid.

Ubuntu base image does not have python3 by default. https://www.cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/noble/release/

It seems that you wrote $ into the command prompt, which is why you got
$: command not found

You are just supposed to write the following in the terminal (don't write $).
sudo apt-get install autoconf automake autotools-dev curl python3 python3-pip libmpc-dev libmpfr-dev libgmp-dev gawk build-essential bison flex texinfo gperf libtool patchutils bc zlib1g-dev libexpat-dev ninja-build git cmake libglib2.0-dev libslirp-dev


sudo apt install build-essential ? might be about the same as above... or at least replace parts of it.

@Hannu My answer addresses the problems faced by OP. If you know exactly which all the duplicate packages, feel free to suggest an edit. I don't have time to go through the dependency of each package/metapackage to determine that

Skipping the $ problem... Well, let it remain as an alternative... you never know which remedies the problem (quickest?)  until you tried.
